# Returning value from function that is convertible to multiple types

Tags: generics, rust

In my library I'm calling a REST API and thus have a common de-serialization function. As is proper the function returns a `Result<T,E>` since the whole process can fail.
In case the process completes successfully I'm returning another `Result<T, E>` where `Ok(T)` indicates the server returned with a 2xx status code and `Err(E)` indicates an 4xx or 5xx error. For each error that can be returned by the API (each request has multiple possibilities) I have, or rather: want to have, one struct that contains the error and additional information about the request.
Now, I could return a generic `ErrorResponse` instead of `E`, and then let the caller convert it via `From but that would mean I'm not using Rust's strong type system and generics, so I'd rather avoid that.

What I want to know is: What would I need to substitute for `E` so that I can automatically de-serialize into the proper error (based on the status code header)? I already tried using `impl From<ErrorResponse>`, but that didn't seem to work.

My de-serialization function currently looks like this:

```rust
pub type DeserializationResult<T> = Result<APIResult<T>, DeserializationError>;
pub type APIResult<T> = Result<DataResponse<T>, ErrorResponse>;
                        // What to change here? -------------^

// I want to get rid of this
#[derive(Debug)]
pub(crate) struct ErrorResponse {
    pub headers: reqwest::header::HeaderMap,
    pub status_code: reqwest::StatusCode,
    pub message: Option<String>,
    // Additional fields removed for brevity
}


#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct ErrorDetails {
    pub id: String,
    pub status: u16,
    pub title: String,
    #[serde(skip_serializing_if = "Option::is_none")]
    pub detail: Option<String>,
    #[serde(skip_serializing_if = "Option::is_none")]
    pub context: Option<String>,
}

#[derive(Error, Debug)]
pub enum DeserializationError {
   // Errors that can occur during deserialization, e.g. "serde_json::Error"
}

pub async fn deserialize_response<T>(response: Response) -> DeserializationResult<T>
    where T: DeserializeOwned,
{
    let status_code = response.status();
    let headers = response.headers().clone();
    let content = response.text().await?;

    if !status_code.is_client_error() && !status_code.is_server_error() {
        let success_result: T = serde_json::from_str(&content)?;
        let data_response = DataResponse {
            status_code,
            headers,
            content: success_result,
        };
        let inner_data = Ok(data_response);
        Ok(inner_data)
    } else {
        let error_result = serde_json::from_str(&content)?;

        let s = StatusCode::from_u16(error_result.status).map_err(|_| DeserializationError::InvalidError)?;
        let error_response = ErrorResponse {
            headers,
            status_code,
            message: error_result.detail.clone(),
        };

        let inner_error = Err(error_response);
        Ok(inner_error)
    }
}
```

And I want to call the function like this:

```rust
let de = deserialization::deserialize_response(server_response).await?;
    match de {
        Ok(data_response) => {
            // Some additional conversion steps
            Ok(data)
        }
        Err(e)=> {
            match e.status_code.as_u16() {
                // Currently the error is manually converted here                
            }
        }
    }
```

Is what I want even possible, or do I need to manually convert the error as I do now?

Comment: Quick tip, Rust has an `Error` trait that marks "error types" and that makes trivial composing them, especially if you use crates like `anyhow` and `thiserror`.

Comment: Using the aforementioned `Error` trait, you can create a "generic" Error that can wrap other kinds of errors, generate backtraces, and so on.

Comment: I'm aware of the two crates and in the lib I'm already using `hiserror, as you might have seen at the `DeserializationError` enum. However, I want to keep "structural errors" (e.g. something that happens in the library) and errors returned by the server mostly separate (that's the reason for the nested `Result`).

Comment: You may create a third enum error type, with a `Something(library::Error)` and a `Server(server::Error)` variant, so that you can extract the reason while abstracting the returned value.